# Spring gRPC - How intercept an exception with body info

Tags: java, spring, grpc, grpc-java

I have a project using spring gRPC. I created a interceptor, when services response succsesfully, the interceptor work fine, but when the service catch an exception, the interceptor not work.

The service:

```
@GrpcService
public class ClientAppImpl extends ClientAppGrpc.ClientAppImplBase {
    
    @Autowired MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void myMethod(Request request, StreamObserver<CreateDigitalCertificateResponse> responseObserver) {
        try {
            Response response = myService.doStuff(request);
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            responseObserver.onError(Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(exception.getMessage()).withCause(exception).asRuntimeException());
        }

    }
}
```

The interceptor:

```
@GrpcGlobalServerInterceptor
public class GrpcServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    public static final String REQUEST_ID_HEADER = "request-id-bin";
    public static final Metadata.Key<byte[]> REQUEST_ID_METADATA_KEY = Metadata.Key.of(REQUEST_ID_HEADER, Metadata.BINARY_BYTE_MARSHALLER);
    private static final Map<String, GrpcCall> CALLS = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

        ForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT> responseServerCall = new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
            @Override
            public void sendMessage(RespT response) {
                String callId = new String(headers.get(REQUEST_ID_METADATA_KEY));

                GrpcCall grpcCall = CALLS.get(callId);
                grpcCall.setResponse(response);

                GrpcCallProcessor grpcCallProcessor = new GrpcCallProcessor(grpcCall);
                grpcCallProcessor.processCall();

                super.sendMessage(response);
            }

        };

        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listenerWithContext = Contexts.interceptCall(Context.current(), responseServerCall, headers, next);

        return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(listenerWithContext) {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(ReqT request) {
                String callId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                headers.put(REQUEST_ID_METADATA_KEY, callId.getBytes());

                GrpcCall grpcCall = new GrpcCall();
                grpcCall.setCall(call);
                grpcCall.setHeaders(headers);
                grpcCall.setRequest(request);

                CALLS.put(callId, grpcCall);

                super.onMessage(request);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When the service not catch an exception, the interceptor work fine, and method sendMessage is called. But when the service catch an exception, the method sendMessage is not called.

Is there any way for intercept an exception, and get de request body in the interceptor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `myService.doStuff()` throws an exception, there *is not any message* being sent. `sendMessage()` won't be called, but `close(Status, Metadata)` still will be.

The current usage of `headers` is broken. `Metadata` is not thread-safe and you do not know what the current "owner" of the object is doing with it. `headers.get(REQUEST_ID_METADATA_KEY)` should be performed within `interceptCall()` directly, before returning.

It isn't entirely clear what the purpose of `onMessage()` is, but it looks like maybe you should make a copy of the metadata (`new Metadata().merge(headers`) within `interceptCall()`.

Comment: [this solution to the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68102211/26510) seems to work for me